# Protect multiple APIs with IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer4 to protect our APIs, actually we have multiple APIs and we want to protect these APIs with IdentityServer4(i.e via generating access tokens) but we have questions regarding validating the access tokens, Do we need to write following code in each API?

```
  public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Actually we are following this tutorial("http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html") and they mentioned we have to describe this in the corresponding API.

Comment: Yes you do. I think that is the whole point. You configure how each API "talks to" Identity Server.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is - **yes you do**.

The explanation - you have to tell each API what authentication to use, and which is the provider.

Depending on the platform (.NET Framework or Core) you should use either [IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation/) (up to date [fork](https://github.com/Rzpeg/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation) of the frozen branch) or IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package.

From what I see - you already have the code for .NET Core approach, and it looks good.

The one for .NET Framework API's can be found [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html#adding-an-api)

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a seperate AuthServer app and write these code inside there.

Then you can validate jwt tokens which generated by your AuthServer using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package.

Your AuthServer should be like that;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var idSrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(
            Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "certs", "yourcert.pfx"), "yourcertpass",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet))
        .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseIdentityServer();
}
```

For IdentityServer configuration you can look at here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html

And in your other apis you can validate jwt tokens like following;

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://YourAuthServerUrl";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                });
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    builder.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Metehan, if we have to create separate auth server as you have mentioned above, then do we need to create multiple auth servers corresponding to each api?

Comment: Because if we mention option.Audience = "api1"; then it will only authorize our "api1" app.

Comment: Hi @Sonika, No you don't create multiple auth server. This code for access token validation and it should be in your api which you want to secure. And "api1" should be your api name. Your api name should be configured in identity resources of identity server.

Comment: but we don't to want to write any code in our api project, because those api already build and deployed

Comment: You must add "IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" nuget package and AddAuthentication and UseAuthentication sections like above in your api project.

Comment: Actually our APIs not build in .NET Core

Comment: So you should use IdentityServer3 for .NET Framework APIs. But same situation also exists there.